# mqAdjust is not defined

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to use mqAdjust from mqGenie. I was using firebug and it called the function and hit the breakpoint where the function is being defined and it gave me an error saying that the function is not defined. Please help:

Script call

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    enquire.register(mqAdjust("screen and (max-width:800px)"), function () {
        console.log("handler 1 matched");
    });
});
```

mqGenie

```
; (function (window, document) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        window.mqAdjust = function (mediaQuery) {
            if (!mqGenie.adjusted)
                return mediaQuery;

            var mq = mediaQuery.replace(/\d+px/gi, function (c) {
                return parseInt(c, 10) + mqGenie.width + 'px';
            });

            mq = mq.replace(/\d.+?em/gi, function (c) {
                return ((parseFloat(c) * mqGenie.fontSize) + mqGenie.width) / mqGenie.fontSize + 'em';
            });

            return mq;
        };
    });
})(window, document);
```

I'm using the latest version of JQuery v.1.10.2
I'm using enquire.js
I'm using mq.genie.js

Links to the documentation on mqGenie and Enquire

https://github.com/stowball/mqGenie

http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/

Answer (score 0):

Since mqGenie is pure javascript and its function is placed within a different type of document.ready (ie DOMContentLoaded), I had to move the functions around on my script to make it work.

Moved all of the functions out of

```
; (function (window, document) {
})(window, document);
```

I also moved the functions within DOMContentLoaded and placed them within my $(document).ready().

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
});
```

To get the unmin version of mqGenie, go to this link: https://github.com/stowball/mqGenie